# Convert all links in wrapper (ID) to open in new tab using only javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using this jquery script to manipulate the html of a specific section of a website. This script just adds target="_blank" to all the links with these classes.

```
<script>
(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#related-products a').attr('target', '_blank');
});
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

However we are not going to be using jquery anymore and I was wondering how to do the same thing in javascript only?

Thanks!

Comment: `#related-products a` means find an element with an `id="related-products"` attribute and then select all `a` tags within that element.  Based on the wording of your question, maybe you instead want `a.related-products` which targets all links with a `class='related-products'` but it would be better if you showed your actual html structure to clarify

Answer (score 1):

```
let anchors = document.querySelectorAll(“#related-products a”);
```

Now, anchors is an array of DOM elements, we need to loop over them and set their *target* attribute:

```
for(let i=0; i<anchors.length; i++){
    anchors[i].setAttribute(‘target’, ‘_blank’);
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this has been downvoted, it looks correct to me. (Except technically `anchors` isn't actually an array - but it's "array-like" enough for the `for` loop to work fine.)

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like the following code. But you need to put your `<script></script>` at the end of `<body></body>` tag to make sure that full document is loaded.

```html
<div id="related-products">
  <a href="www.google.com">It will open in new tab</a>
</div>
<a href="www.example.com">It will not open in new tab</a>
<script>
  (function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('#related-products a');
    elems.forEach(function(elem) {
      elem.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
    });
  })();
</script>
```

Comment: Please explain why you put the downvote and how my answer can be improved.